# 'Pythonic' way to assure length of matrix elements

Tags: python, idioms

Given a list of lists:

```
>>> n=4
>>> LoL=[range(n) for i in range(n)]
>>> LoL
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Is it readily apparent, understandable, *Pythonic* even to assure a N x N matrix this way:

```
>>> len(LoL) == n and {len(l) for l in LoL} == {n}
True
```

So it would be used thus:

```
if len(matrix) != 4 or {len(l) for l in matrix} != {4}:
        raise ValueError
```

Is there a better alternative idiom or is this understandable?

Comment: Yes. Use NumPy.

Comment: `all(len(l) == n for l in LoL)` is better

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Just to assure the NxN size of a List of List -- use Numpy?? That seems like overkill...

Comment: @JBernardo: good suggestion, but you would need to add the overall list length: `all(len(l)==n for l in LoL) and len(LoL)==n`, no? Make that an answer...

Comment: @carrot-top: But surely you don't *just* want to assure the NxN size.  You say in the title that it's a "matrix".  You're going to be doing other stuff with these objects, and for that Numpy is likely to be useful.

Comment: `all([len(l)==n for l in LoL]+[len(LoL)==n])` but I agree w others that you should probably use np if you have to do much at all with the matrix...

Comment: @BrenBarn: Humbly, yes -- just a data element (from many) that needs to be only 4 x 4 list of lists. The processing is minimal on the LoL but breaks if something other than 4 X 4

Comment: Matrices are useful in contexts outside of Numpy, PIL for example.

Comment: Why the downvote? This seems like a reasonable question of an understandable idiom for determining a LoL is 4x4? A try / except could be used I suppose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in your comment, try / except is probably better.

Not only will you catch and attempt to use an element outside of the 4x4 size, but you will also catch the wrong dimensions passed to you:

```
>>> LoL=[1,2,3,4]
>>> len(LoL) == n and {len(l) for l in LoL} == {n}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <setcomp>
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Vs, if you have doubt about the data you are about to use:

```
>>> try: 
...    i=LoL[2][2]
... except IndexError:
...    print 'no bueno...'
... 
no bueno...
```

Comment: Please, don't use plain `except:`